# Bootstrap 5 Badges don't apper properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add bage on label, but It only make my text color white

```
<asp:Label CssClass="badge badge-pill badge-success" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct usage should be like this.

Use bg-succes instead of badge-success

```
<asp:Label CssClass="badge badge-pill bg-success" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```